# How to use two expression in a sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table

`MARKS`:

- Roll
- SubA (contains subject code)
- SubB (contains subject code)
- SubC (contains subject code)
- ....
- ....

`SUBJECT`:

- Sub_Code
- Sub_Name
- Sub_Opt  (contains option like theory / practical)

When I write this query

```
Select 
    Roll, 
    (Select Sub_Name From Subject Wwhere dbo.marks.subA = dbo.subject.sub_code), 
    (Select Sub_Name From Subject where dbo.marks.SubB = dbo.subject.sub_code) 
from marks, subject
```

it runs successfully, but when I try to add subject option within subquery Like -

```
    select 
    Roll, 
    ( SELECT    Sub_name ,
                Sub_Opt
      FROM      subject
      WHERE     dbo.marks.SubA = dbo.subject.Sub_Code
    ) 
    ( SELECT    Sub_name ,
                Sub_Opt
      FROM      subject
      WHERE     dbo.marks.SubB = dbo.subject.Sbu_Code
    ) 
from Marks, subject
```

it causes an error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I want result in this format

```
ROLL, SUB_NAME_A, SUB_OPT_A, SUB_NAME_B, SUB_OPT_B, SUB_NAME_C, SUB_OP_C,......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `join` on the tables, you might need a `LEFT JOIN` in place of inner if there's no guarantee of data in the `SUBJECT` table

```
   SELECT  m.Roll ,
            a.Sub_name ,
            a.Sub_Opt ,
            b.Sub_name ,
            b.Sub_Opt
    FROM    marks m
            INNER JOIN SUBJECT a ON m.SubA = a.Sub_Code
            INNER JOIN SUBJECT b ON m.SubB = b.Sub_Code
            etc
```

Answer (score 0):

select 
    Roll, 
    ( SELECT    Sub_name 
                 FROM      subject
      WHERE     dbo.marks.SubA = dbo.subject.Sub_Code
    ) SUB_NAME_A ,
    ( SELECT    Sub_Opt 
      FROM      subject
      WHERE     dbo.marks.SubA = dbo.subject.Sub_Code
    ) SUB_OPT_A ,

```
( SELECT    Sub_name 
  FROM      subject
  WHERE     dbo.marks.SubB = dbo.subject.Sub_Code
)  SUB_NAME_B ,
( SELECT    Sub_Opt 
  FROM      subject
  WHERE     dbo.marks.SubB = dbo.subject.Sub_Code
) SUB_OPT_B ,
```

from Marks

```
this also should work
```